# How to split large Excel file into multiple Excel files using R

Tags: r, excel, filesplitting

I'm looking for a way to split up a large Excel file into a number of smaller Excel files using R.

Specifically, there are three things I would like to do:

1. I have a large data set consisting of information regarding students (their school, the area in which the school is located, test score A, test score B) that I would like to split up into individual files, one file per school containing all of the students attending that specific school.
2. I would also like all of the individual Excel files to contain an image covering the first row and columns A, B, C & D of every Excel file. The image will be the same for all the schools in the data set.
3. Lastly, I would also like the Excel files, after being created, to end up in individual folders on my desktop. The folders name would be the area in which the schools are located. An area has about 3-5 schools so the folder would contain 3-5 Excel files, 1 for each school.

My data is structured like this:

| Area | School | Student ID | Test score A | Test score B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| North | A | 134 | 24 | 31 |
| North | A | 221 | 26 | 33 |
| South | B | 122 | 22 | 21 |
| South | B | 126 | 25 | 25 |

I have data covering roughly 200 schools located in 5 different areas.

Any guidance on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think without more information about the files and data included you can not get more specific answers than ‘read Excel files’ -> ‘do some data transformation’ -> ‘split into smaller groups’ -> ‘save into the appropriate folders’. What have you tried? What works? What doesn’t?

Comment: agreed, does not seem too complicated splitting your bigger file into smaller files and then save them using the information of the columns and some `paste` command. you could just use simple loops if the files is not too big. 
I dont understand what you mean in 2. with the image.

Comment: The Image sees to refer to somesort of logo or report header (If I'm not mistaken).. || If using R.. u can only get [1] done. [2] & [3] is not (afaik) doable using R. || btw, column A,B,C,D refers to which ( Area/ School /Student ID / Test score A / B ) one?

Comment: Correct, the image is a form of logo. I want it to cover the first row and 4 columns of every Excel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments have referenced, this will be hard to solve without knowing your specific operating environment & folder structure, I solved this using Windows 10/ C drive user folder but you can customize to your system.  You're going to need a folder with all the images from the school saved by the name (or the ID I created) of the school and they will all need to be the same format (JPG or PNG).  Plus, you need folders created for each Area you want to output to (openxlsx can write the files but not create the folders for you).  Once you have those setup, something similar to this should work for you, but I would highly recommend referring to the openxlsx documentation for more info:

```
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)

# Load your excel file into a df
# g0 = openxlsx::read.xlsx(<your excel file & sheet..see openxlsx documentation>)

# Replace this tibble with your actual excel file, this was just for an example
g0 = tibble(
  Area = c("North","North","North","North"),
  School = c("A","A","B","B"),
  Student_ID = c(134,221,122,126),
  test_score_a = c(24,26,22,25),
  test_score_b = c(31,33,21,25))

# Need a numeric school id for the loop
g0$school_id = as.numeric(as.factor(g0$School))

# Loop through schools, filter using dplyr and create a sheet per school
for (i in 1:n_distinct(g0$school_id)){
  g1 = g0 %>% 
  filter(school_id == i)
  
  ## Create a new workbook
  wb <- createWorkbook(as.character(g1$School))
  
  ## Add some worksheets
  addWorksheet(wb, as.character(g1$School))
  
  ## Insert images
  ## I left the image as a direct path for example but you can change to a
  ## relative path once you get it working
  img <- system.file("C:","Users","your name","Documents","A","A.jpg", package = "openxlsx")
  insertImage(wb, as.character(g1$School), img, startRow = 5, startCol = 3, width = 6, height = 5)

  ## Save workbook
  saveWorkbook(wb, paste0("C://Users//your name//Documents//",g0$Area,"//",g0$school,".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
}
```